# Javascript/jQuery unit testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unit-testing

I want to start writing Unit tests for my JS code, i have never done this before, never had the need, but as my projects are ever expanding think it's time to start.

Now writing the tests themselves i don't think will be an issue for functional javascript code (a function that adds two numbers together), i don't have that, all of those things are server side (as it's much more complex than adding two digits), what i do have (and a lot of it) is dynamic Javascript (and jQuery) which is intertwined with HTML and my question is, how (and can i) write tests for that? Same code bellow (completely lorem ispum)

```
MyHelperClass = function () {
    var _someBool = false;

    return {
        Initialize: function () {
            MyHelperClass.ChangeALotOfThings("init");
        },

        ChangeALotOfThings: function (arg1) {
            var $someID = $("#myID");
            var _anotherBool = true;

            if ($someID.lenght) {
                var moreHTML = MyOtherHelperClass.ThisFunctionWillReturnSomeHTML();

                $someID.find(".myClass").append(moreHTML);
                $(".someClass").on("click", function(){
                    // do some code | i.e. basic Accordion 
                });

                if (_anotherBool && arg1) {
                    var result = $.ajax({
                            url: "test.html",
                            context: document.body
                        });

                    $someID.prepend(result);    
                }
            } else {
                // do other similar stuff
            }
        }
    }
}

MyHelperClass.Initialize();
```

This is a random example i wrote in 5min (some .js/jQuery syntax isn't even correct) and think the code doesn't even make a lot of sense, bottom line is, can something like this be Unit Tested?

I was looking into Tape.js and Jasmine.js but couldn't find much.
Thank you for any comments and/or advice regarding writing Unit Test for .js/jQuery.